# Best Programming Language for Web Development

Tags: programming-languages, web-development

I am a Web Developer in PHP, and also know Javascript and some bit of CSS which is needed for web development. I use Symfony framework to build Websites and Web Application. As now i want to learn new Programming Language, which is best for Web Development(like Ruby, Python), as i have heard about Frameworks like Rails and Django. 
Which language will be best for Web Development apart from PHP or like PHP?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: yeah thats right @Anto.

Comment: Which language is best to write a good novel? English? Spanish? French?

Comment: @Abimaran it depends upon which language you Know or comfortable with. yeah i got the point. because you can do the same thing with Ruby, Python, Java or PHP...but depends upon what you know the best.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it is impossible to give a definitive answer to your question.

To determine what is best in a particular situation you should look at

- What are the important requirements for the site?

  - Response times?
  - Scalability?
  - Concurrent users needing to be handled?
- What are your developers' skill sets?
- How will the site be hosted?
- Do you have to work with an existing code base?
- Personal preference of the developers/management etc (Not everyone works the same, hence langauge benefits will vary from person to person)
- Skills available in the current job market
- Many more...

The language someone will use will depend on how the questions above are answered.

Comment: mcGrath yeah definitely..it depends upon the need of the project.

Comment: and in some cases the alignment of the moon :)

Comment: we cannot say Python is the best language for web over PHP or Ruby, Java, etc...because it depends on the conditions and requirements of project.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the language you really like.
node.js
pyjamas
RoR
ActionScript 3 (flash, flex)
Javascript, html, css etc.